# Does the divergent solution of this equation :$f'=e^{f^{-1}}$ of Gevrey type and could be Borel summation applied for it?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-equations, power-series, integer-sequences

This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/258525/99666) was asked here in  MO by someone seeking for the solution of the functional -differential:$f'=e^{f^{-1}}$ not exactly an O.D.E, and again [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/258611/99666) seeking for the growth rate of it solution  .  this lead me to ask the following question which include some addition in the side of  it's  behavior which it related to the existence  of divergent solution of **Gevrey type** and **the Borel summation** .then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     Does the divergent solution of this equation :$f'=e^{f^{-1}}$ of Gevrey type and could be Borel summation applied for it ?.or any reference discussed that ?

**Note**:The motivation of this question is to seek if the Borel sum is analytic solution for the equation .

Comment: Borel summation could be applied  if the solution is an asymptotic series

Comment: I think to start a bounty for this question it's very interesting

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that , could you help me for that ?

Comment: ok, no problem since it's interesting and it's include my question